# How to create a Javascript listener that triggers an event once a div's children all have a particular class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a clickable tile game:

example here:

http://adaptive.womworld.com/facebook-tabs/demo/

there's 3 stages and I wanted the app to listen for when all the tiles had the class name select that it would then remove the parent.

At the moment, you have to click to remove this, but if possible i'd like it to happen once the last tile is clicked, regardless of which one.

None of my attempts have been successful, any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Well, include the check whenever a tile is clicked...

Comment: Include a few of your attempts and maybe we can help you improve them. You also need to include html/code in your question, a link to an external resource isn't good enough.

Comment: You should put meaningful excerpt of javascript here along with description of what the code intends to do rather than requiring everyone to dig through your source code to try to figure out what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many tiles there are total, you can check if the number of tiles with the class equals the total number of tiles.

```
if($('#tileWrapper .myclass').length == numTotalTiles) {...}
```

Just call that at the end of every tile click event.

Comment: Or inversely just look for `$('.class_being_removed').length == 0` on the class that is being removed to know when you have all of them removed.